# Iterating through a matrix using a smaller matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've been struggling with this for a bit now. I have a small matrix `s` for example and a bigger matrix `B` as shown below.

```
B =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0

s =
     1     1
     1     1
```

What I want to do is iterate through `B` with `s` and compare the values. If all the values in `s` equal the values in `B` (the small section of `B`), then the answer is 1, if not then 0.

The `1's` and `0's` would be placed in a matrix as well.

This is what I've done so far but unfortunately, it doesn't iterate step by step and doesn't create a matrix either.

```
s = ones(2,2)

B = randi([0 1],8,8)

f = zeros(size(B))

[M,N]=size(B);   % the larger array
[m,n]=size(s);   % and the smaller...

for i=1:M/m-(m-1)
  for j=1:N/n-(n-1)
    if all(s==B(i:i+m-1,j:j+n-1))
      disp("1")
    else
        disp("0")
    end
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're not getting enough steps because you're dividing by the size of the smaller array, which is incorrect. (Count how many steps there should be across the top row and down the leftmost column to see what these should be.) Also, you never assign any values to your output matrix `f`. Do you really need to use loops? This would be one line using [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following code works on the examples you supplied, I haven't tested it on anything else, and it will not work if the dimensions of the smaller matrix are not factors of the dimensions of the larger matrix, but you didn't indicate that it needed to do that in your description.

```
B =[0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
 1     1     0     0     1     0     1     1
 1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1
 1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
 0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0];

S =[1     1
 1     1];

%check if array meets size requirements
numRowB = size(B,1);
numRowS = size(S,1);
numColB = size(B,2);
numColS = size(S,2);

%get loop multiples
incRows = numRowB/numRowS;
incCols = numColB/numColS;

%create output array
result = zeros(incRows, incCols);

%create rows and colums indices
rowsPull = 1:numRowS:numRowB;
colsPull = 1:numColS:numColB;

%iterate
for i= 1:incRows
    for j= 1:incCols
        result(i,j) = isequal(B(rowsPull(i):rowsPull(i)+numRowS-1, colsPull(j):colsPull(j)+numColS-1),S);
    end
end

%print the resulting array
disp(result)
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle, how do you do if they're not factors?

Comment: It's not clear from your initial post how you want to handle sets of matrices that do not tile perfectly. Can you clarify how you see that working? You could reject matrices that don't fit, or compute only the parts of the two matrices that overlap when you get to an irregular edge, or something else?